# How to handle infinite loop in threads and avoid memory leak

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks

I have a project which run several infinite loops in threads, I simplify it to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/fiber/algo/round_robin.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <chrono> 
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <string>

void foo(){
    std::cout<<"thread a"<<std::endl;
    while(true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{5});
    }
    return;
}
void foo2(){
    std::cout<<"thread b"<<std::endl;
    while(true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{5});
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    std::thread a(foo);
    std::thread b(foo2);
    while(true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{5});
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected.
I use valgrind to detect memory leak and it shows it has memory leak(I guess infinite loop never release memory because it never stops). I considered to use join(), but it doesn't make sense here. I tried to add

```
a.detach();
b.detach();
```

before the while loop in main function, but it doesn't solve memory leak issue.

Would somebody please give me some advice how to avoid memory leak here?

Comment: when your program cannot terminate in a "normal" way why worry about the leaks? I am certain that you do not really need threads that cannot be joined. What is your actual aim?

Comment: Yes if you detach threads that you never join before the process shuts down that is technically a memory leak. But do you care about it? If so then you need to signal the threads to stop and then join them. You can't have infinitely looping threads if you want "correctness".

Comment: Signal your threads to stop, i.e. with a `stop_token` or an `atomic<bool>`, then `join()` them.

Comment: Minor point: you don't need those `return;` statements in `foo` and `foo2`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks for your help. For foo and foo1 functions, in my original code, which are two infinite loops which are tracking the status of other running applications, so they should never stop.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for your help. I'm a new coder, I know the "return" will never be reached in those functions, but are there any other issues if I leave the "return" there?

Comment: "they should never stop" and I think you should reconsider this. Even a 24/7 running code must terminate eventually at some point. Make the threads joinable and then maybe not only this but also other issues will be gone

Comment: @PeterT Thanks for your help. I have poor understandings of memory leaks. It just shows errors by running with valgrind so I'm just wondering if I can find a way to avoid leaks. If not, it's still fine.

Comment: detaching a thread is rarely the right solution. Actually whenever I thought I should detach a thread in the long run it turned out to be a bad mistake

Comment: @JonathanS. Thanks for your help. In my original code, those two loops are tracking the status of other running applications, my intend was to let them run all the time.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm a little confused. These two loops should stop when this running process stops. My intend was let it run all the time before manually stop.

Comment: [Infinite loop without side-effects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Infinite_loop_without_side-effects) is Undefined Behavior!

Comment: Re, "are there any other issues if I leave the "return" there? " The return statement is a distraction for somebody who is trying to read and understand your code. It seems to say the opposite of what you intend for the routine to do. If you you study software engineering, a large part of what they teach you just comes down to different ways of making your code easy for your peers and your co-workers (and _yourself_ when you come back to change something months later) to read and understand

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for replying me. I didn't pay attention to this issue, but I will be more careful in my future code.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/aodr4Thd1 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a long answer, so I'll start with a summary: The leak in your example code is not an issue. Nevertheless you should fix it. And the way to fix it is to turn the infinite loops into non-infinite loops and to join the threads.

---

A memory leak is for example this:

```
void bar() {
    int * x = new int;
}
```

An object is dynamically allocated and when the function returns all pointers to the object are lost. The memory is still allocated to the process but you cannot free it. Calling `bar` many times will pile up memory until the process runs out of memory and gets killed. This is to be avoided.

Then there is a less severe type of memory leaks:

```
 int main() {
      bar();
 }
```

Here some memory is allocated, but next the process terminates. When the process terminates all memory is reclaimed by the OS. The missing `delete` is not such a big issue here.

There are other ways of leaking memory and I am not trying to enumerate them all, but rather use the examples to get a point across.

Then there are good reasons to worry also about this second type of leaks, that I called "less severe". And that is because it is typically not just memory that is leaked. Consider (dont write code like this! it is only for illustrating a point):

```
   int main() {
       A* = new A();
   }
```

`A` is some class. In `main` some memory is allocated and an `A` is constructed. The memory is the lesser problem here. The real problem is any other resource that `A` claimed in its constructor. It might have opened a file. It might have opened a connection to a data base. Such resources must be cleaned up in a destructor. If the `A` object is not properly destroyed critical data might get lost.

Conclusion: Leaking memory when returning from `main` isn't a big issue. Leaking other resource is a big issue. And the memory leak is good indication that also other resources are not cleaned up properly.

In your toy example there is no problem but only a small change makes your approach problematic:

```
void foo(){
    A a;
    while(true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{5});
    }
}
```

`A` is again the class that acquires some resource in its constructor and that resouce must be properly release in the destructor. Also when the program terminates you want to have the data in the database, the last log message in the log file, etc.

Rather than `while(true)` and `detach` you should use some atomic or condition variable to signal the threads that they should stop. Something along the line of

```
std::atomic<bool> foo_runs;

void foo(){
    A a;
    while(foo_runs.load()){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{5});
    }
}

int main() {
    foo_runs.store(true);
    std::thread a(foo);
    // do something else 
    
    foo_runs.store(false);
    a.join();
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, there are more ways to have memory leaks. General definition is any memory which is no longer reachable by program logic. Other examples of memory leak: cycle of strong references, bug in logic which makes some instance of some object ethereal.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, you have to `join()/detach()` on `a` and `b`. If you call `join()` before the main loop, you'll never get to the main loop. If you get to the end of `main()` without `join()`/`detach()`, `std::abort()` will be called.

I don't see a leak, but there is a race on the `cout` stream. Maybe potential leak can happen if detached thread `a` or `b` escapes `main()` and continues running a never-ending function. In such case, the thread itself is leaked since it is detached from `*this` (main), and there is no owner to destroy it. If that's the story, try to call `join()` on both `a` and `b` after the main loop.